# WPF- Pull data from XML

Tags: c#

I have to pull data data from an XML file to a WPF screen (i am trying to achieve this in C#.NET).
The XML file contains one parent tag i.e. Databse and 5 children with no attributes.

I have to pull this data to a WPF grid and then to its associated text boxes.
I am stuck with this from past 4 days, Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks,
Indu.

Comment: What have you tried? which errors do you get? show us a relevant piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach,

- Create an object which will represnt your XML
- Create a property of
  above object in XAML.cs or ViewModel (if using prism)
- Load XML and / or de-serialize to your object in the property
- Bind the object properties on XAML

Sample XML

```
<ParentTag><ChildTag>Somevalue</ChildTag></ParentTag>
```

Sample Object

```
public class ParentTag {
   public string ChildTag {get;set;}
}
```

Load XML using Serializer

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new
XmlSerializer(typeof(ParentTag));

// A FileStream is needed to read the XML document.
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);

// Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
ParentTag item;

// Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
item = (ParentTag)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
fs.Close();
```

Create property in CS file

```
public ParentTag ParentTagProperty{ get;set;}
```

Now bind on XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentTagProperty}"/>
```

I hope you understand missing steps in explanation.